# Remove Redundance via bash

Tags: bash, sorting, grep, data-manipulation

I have this problem, I have the following lines:

```
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&id=532&prTpID=5&
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&prTpID=5&
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?upTp=2&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2&prTpID=5&&ptype=FS
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre&ca=2412
```

And I want to remove every line that has every parameter on another line, let's say, this two lines:

```
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre&ca=2412
```

I want to keep this one only:

```
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre&ca=2412
```

Because is the one with more parameters and the first one would be redundant.

I would like to keep this ones:

```
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&id=532&prTpID=5&
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?upTp=2&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2&prTpID=5&&ptype=FS
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre&ca=2412
```

I want to remove every line that has the same parameters on other lines, keep the ones that have more parameters, not the ones that have fewer.

Another example:

I want to convert this:

```
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=111
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewNews&ID=390
http://grouplogic.com:80/public/quickpoll/index.cfm?fuseaction=quickPollResults&QuestionID=8
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&id=532&prTpID=5&
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?upTp=2&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2&prTpID=5&&ptype=FS
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewRelease&ID=21&prod=2
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?fuseaction=faq_list&ProdID=1&archive=1
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=103
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&amp
http://grouplogic.com:80/knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=10
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123
```

into this:

```
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=111
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewRelease&ID=21&prod=2
http://grouplogic.com:80/public/quickpoll/index.cfm?fuseaction=quickPollResults&QuestionID=8
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&id=532&prTpID=5&
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?upTp=2&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2&prTpID=5&&ptype=FS
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?fuseaction=faq_list&ProdID=1&archive=1
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=103
```

Same parameters in different resource, must be different lines.

If I got this:

```
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123
http://grouplogic.com:80/content2/index.cfm?ID=123
```

I want to keep them both.

EDIT 19th August:

---

Another example of URLs and how I would like them to be handled:

```
https://es.answers.search.yahoo.com/search?p=mixmail+correo&fr2=piv-web
https://es.answers.search.yahoo.com/search?p=educastur+campus&fr2=piv-web
https://techvalidation.dell.com/Default.aspx?id=9d459f5c-8a26-4268-b37c-23980a6ba577&Key=%2fuKb2WS3da4lk%2f34VSXE4F02YqS5LfvbKFGcDXNQxgIvvbodU3o3lHoNm09M67Ut&SRC=QuoteCenter&newsession=true
https://techvalidation.dell.com/technicalvalidationlist.aspx?key=6ivAYJco9bouAJBNkQ8rgtGWPdfLVRumAScf7bIb6DMpj6SYVdWy6bd4ITEPF4tQMkNzNpGshERZndX3Ia%2bbqhJ3CnrC46qJkHJ4TdiyN78%3d&PartnerAffinityId=3341728904&SRC=QuoteCenter
https://web.xnet.ford.com/3.0/samlerror?faultreason=SSO_LOGOFF
https://web.xnet.ford.com/3.0/samlerror?faultreason=SSO_ERROR&language=fr
https://wwwmg.pandacn.ford.com/forms/frmservlet?config=pandacn3
https://www.panda.ford.com/forms/frmservlet?config=pandain4
https://www.panda.ford.com/forms/frmservlet?config=pandain3
```

It should output:

```
https://es.answers.search.yahoo.com/search?p=mixmail+correo&fr2=piv-web
https://techvalidation.dell.com/Default.aspx?id=9d459f5c-8a26-4268-b37c-23980a6ba577&Key=%2fuKb2WS3da4lk%2f34VSXE4F02YqS5LfvbKFGcDXNQxgIvvbodU3o3lHoNm09M67Ut&SRC=QuoteCenter&newsession=true
https://techvalidation.dell.com/technicalvalidationlist.aspx?key=6ivAYJco9bouAJBNkQ8rgtGWPdfLVRumAScf7bIb6DMpj6SYVdWy6bd4ITEPF4tQMkNzNpGshERZndX3Ia%2bbqhJ3CnrC46qJkHJ4TdiyN78%3d&PartnerAffinityId=3341728904&SRC=QuoteCenter
https://web.xnet.ford.com/3.0/samlerror?faultreason=SSO_ERROR&language=fr
https://wwwmg.pandacn.ford.com/forms/frmservlet?config=pandacn3
https://www.panda.ford.com/forms/frmservlet?config=pandain4
```

My approach just works on URLs with just one parameter:

```
https://www.panda.ford.com/forms/frmservlet?config=pandain4
https://www.panda.ford.com/forms/frmservlet?config=pandain3
```

I do: `cat list.txt | sort -u -t "=" -k 1,1` and I output:

```
https://www.panda.ford.com/forms/frmservlet?config=pandain4
```

But it fails with these ones:

```
https://web.xnet.ford.com/3.0/samlerror?faultreason=SSO_LOGOFF
https://web.xnet.ford.com/3.0/samlerror?faultreason=SSO_ERROR&language=fr
```

Where I keep

```
https://web.xnet.ford.com/3.0/samlerror?faultreason=SSO_LOGOFF
```

with `| cat list.txt | sort -u -t "=" -k 1,1` and I wanted exactly the other line

```
https://web.xnet.ford.com/3.0/samlerror?faultreason=SSO_ERROR&language=fr
```

Because it has the same parameters and more.

Regards!

---

Comment: you could do it in multiple steps, sort that and recursive match shorter in longer strings with grep, add the non matching last

Comment: Why is `http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewNews&ID=390` from the first set not in the second set?

Comment: You never answer this. Why is `http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123` in the first set but not the second? You will have to clarify your criteria.

Comment: Are the double-ampersands in `http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?upTp=2&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2&prTpID=5&&ptype=FS` intended/required? or the ampersand at the END of `http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&id=532&prTpID=5&`?

Comment: Wait - are you saying you don't care what VALUES were passed, you only want one of a set as long as the KEYS are all the same???

Answer (score 2):

Doing this properly requires a lot of internal sorting which inside a `bash` loop spawns a lot of processes and slows the job down too much.

Switching to `perl`. Note that this reorders arguments as well as lines; if you need the original lines untouched and/or in the original order, we'll have to add another step or three. You should also note that you have `knowledge` both capitalized and lowercase; url's are case insensitive through the port, but path after that is case sensitive, so they will not register as the same even if they get identical arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;     # I ALWAYS use strict and warnings unless 
use warnings;   # there is some compelling reason not to.

open my $fh, 'urls' or die "urls: $!";
my %urlsOUT;
foreach ( <$fh> ) { chomp;
    my %args;                              # clean for each record
    m!^(https?://[^/]+)(/[^?]+)[?](.*)!i;  # catch the base in separate case sensitivities
    my ($base) = lc($1).$2;                # always lowercase the case insensitive part
    @args{ split /[?&]+/, $3 } = ();       # removes duplicate args in a url
    my ( $args ) = join '&', reverse sort keys %args; # reassemle ORDERED
    $urlsOUT{"$base?$args"}='';            # now a unique key
}

my $urlsOUT='';
REC: foreach my $url (reverse sort keys %urlsOUT ) { # ORDERED
       for ( split /[?&]/, $url ) {                  # for each arg
         if ( $urlsOUT !~ /\b$_\b/ ) {               # if new
           $urlsOUT .= "$url\n";                     # keep this
           next REC;                                 # check next
         }
       }
}

print $urlsOUT;
```

This will consistently reorder and de-dup all arguments in a URL, de-dup all resulting records, and then check each remaining record (in descending order) to eliminate any record that doesn't have *something* no other record before it had.

I named the program file `tst` and made a `tst1` and a `urls`.

```
$: cat tst1
http://test/foo?foo
http://test/foo?bar
http://test/foo?foo
http://test2/foo?foo
http://test2/foo?baz
http://test2/foo?foo&bar
http://test2/foo?baz
http://test/foo?foo&bar
http://test/foo?bar&foo
http://test2/foo?bar&foo
http://test3/foo?bar
http://test3/foo?foo&bar&baz
http://test2/foo?foo&bar&baz
http://test/foo?foo&bar&baz

$: ./tst tst1
http://test3/foo?foo&baz&bar
http://test2/foo?foo&baz&bar
http://test/foo?foo&baz&bar

$: cat urls
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=111
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewNews&ID=390
http://grouplogic.com:80/public/quickpoll/index.cfm?fuseaction=quickPollResults&QuestionID=8
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&id=532&prTpID=5&
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?upTp=2&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2&prTpID=5&&ptype=FS
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewRelease&ID=21&prod=2
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?fuseaction=faq_list&ProdID=1&archive=1
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=103
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&amp
http://grouplogic.com:80/knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=10
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=111
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewNews&ID=390
http://grouplogic.com:80/public/quickpoll/index.cfm?fuseaction=quickPollResults&QuestionID=8
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123&foo=bar
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&id=532&prTpID=5&
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?    upTp=2&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2&prTpID=5&&ptype=FS
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewRelease&ID=21&prod=2
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?fuseaction=faq_list&ProdID=1&archive=1
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=103
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&amp
http://grouplogic.com:80/knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=10
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123

$: ./tst urls
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?upTp=2&ptype=FS&prTpID=5&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?prTpID=5&id=532&fa=PrtSlt
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=conre&cftoken=26157811&cfid=11812682
http://grouplogic.com:80/public/quickpoll/index.cfm?fuseaction=quickPollResults&QuestionID=8
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?prod=2&fa=viewRelease&ID=21
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewNews&ID=390
http://grouplogic.com:80/knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=10
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?fuseaction=faq_list&archive=1&ProdID=1
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?foo=bar&ID=123
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=103
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=111
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&amp
```

Note the outputs are case-sensitive ASCII sorted, with trailing and duplicate/redundant ampersands cleaned.

Doing it in `perl` with internal reads and sorts is also a lot faster.

```
real    0m0.170s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.092s
```

---

#### the old version

I see no more elegant way than a brute-force double pass, though you can at least eliminate redundant comparisons in the nested loop.

```
lst=( $( sort -ru x ) ) # unique reverse sort once to eliminate simple dups

for (( ndx1=0; ndx1<${#lst[@]}-1; ndx1++ ))       # walk thru once in outer loop
do [[ -n "${lst[ndx1]}" ]] || continue            # ignore removed
   for (( ndx2=ndx1+1; ndx2<${#lst[@]}; ndx2++ )) # inner skips prev, no redux
   do case "${lst[ndx1]}" in                      # case statement string match
      "${lst[ndx2]}"*) unset lst[ndx2] ;;         # remove shorter versions
                    *) continue 2      ;;         # no match, skip ahead
      esac
   done
done

printf "%s\n" "${lst[@]}"                         # print out what's left
```

I `sort` uniquely in reverse order to eliminate simple dups and set up comparisons, and store to an array for easy nested looping.

The outer loop walks the array once; it doesn't bother with the last record, because the inner loop will handle that. The inner loop starts at the record after the current one from the outer loop - no reason to check previous again since they are sorted.

Since the inner loop removed records, the outer loop skips checking entirely if the outer key record at the indicated index is empty.

The `case` statement checks each record *after* the current one from the outer loop. If the inner key is contained in the current outer loop key record, the shorter version is removed from the array with `unset`, and the loop proceeds to the next record to check that.

When the inner loop record is no longer a part of the outer loop key, we know we have moved past the relevant records (since they are sorted), so we skip checking the rest of the list pointlessly and move on to the next outer key record with `continue 2`.

This moving window of relevant records should do minimal wasted work.

Comment: There is a possible case sensitivity issue.

Comment: I am using your program with the url list as a parameter and I get the same results, I mean, there is no one line deleted =(

Comment: This assumes matching case and order or all arguments. Am I missing something relevant?

Comment: If your order of arguments varies, this becomes an exponentially more complex problem.

Comment: Hi. The argument is a list of urls, it can be any list of urls and should remove all the lines that have arguments that are redundant because other lines with the same, or, the same and more, have them.

Comment: can you tell how do you use the perl script? `perl paramsort.pl lista.txt`  gives me 
`urls: No such file or directory at paramsort.pl line 6.` `perl paramsort.pl` with a file called "urls" doesn't work either, how u use it? Thanks!

Comment: does the new version work for you? Have you got a PoC?

Comment: Added my test files and outputs. That'll be a nickle. ;)

Comment: Hi I tested it, and it works for these cases you are right, but not for every set of URLs: https://snipboard.io/sGSH4d.jpg , Regards

Comment: Edit your original post to use a valid set of test URL's - NOT an image, please, lol. We'll get it handled. Also, I don't see why you highlighted the boxed urls in your image. Please explain.

Comment: Hi! I Highlighted them because they were the ones that must be removed, because they are duplicated, sorry I didn't indicated it in the image, I forgot it

Comment: You still haven't explained why `http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewNews&ID=390` is being removed in your data. Is it because the KEYS are case-insensitively redundant, and you aren't considering their VALUES???

Answer (score 0):

Finally, looks like i've done it) for this test file:

```
$ cat file2
test?foo
test?bar
test?foo
test2?foo
test2?baz
test2?foo&bar
test2?baz
test?foo&bar
test?bar&foo
test2?bar&foo
test3?bar
test3?foo&bar&baz
test2?foo&bar&baz
test?foo&bar&baz
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A resorces
raw=( $(sort -u $1) )
for url in "${raw[@]}"; { resorces[${url//\?*}]+=" ${url//*\?}"; }
for res in "${!resorces[@]}"; {
    list=( ${resorces[$res]} )
    for i in "${!list[@]}"; {
        par=${list[$i]}
        unset list[$i]
        [[ ${list[@]} =~ $par ]] || result+=("$res?$par")
    }
}
printf '%s\n' "${result[@]}"
```

Result

```
$ ./test2 file2
test2?bar&foo
test2?foo&bar&baz
test3?foo&bar&baz
test?bar&foo
test?foo&bar&baz
```

And for this test file:

```
$ cat file
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=111
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewNews&ID=390
http://grouplogic.com:80/public/quickpoll/index.cfm?fuseaction=quickPollResults&QuestionID=8
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&id=532&prTpID=5&
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?upTp=2&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2&prTpID=5&&ptype=FS
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewRelease&ID=21&prod=2
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?fuseaction=faq_list&ProdID=1&archive=1
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=103
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&amp
http://grouplogic.com:80/knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=10
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123&foo=bar
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123&foo=bar
```

Result

```
$ ./test2 file
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?fuseaction=faq_list&ProdID=1&archive=1
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=103
http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=123&foo=bar
http://grouplogic.com:80/public/quickpoll/index.cfm?fuseaction=quickPollResults&QuestionID=8
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&amp
http://grouplogic.com:80/Knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=111
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?cfid=11812682&cftoken=26157811&fa=conre
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?fa=PrtSlt&id=532&prTpID=5&
http://grouplogic.com:80/store/index.cfm?upTp=2&fa=upgrade&UpNewType=2&prTpID=5&&ptype=FS
http://grouplogic.com:80/knowledge/index.cfm?fuseaction=view&docID=10
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewNews&ID=390
http://grouplogic.com:80/news-events/index.cfm?fa=viewRelease&ID=21&prod=2
```

Comment: Eliminates dups, but doesn't remove lesser subsets of parms.

Comment: add `http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=103&foo=bar` to your dataset, it still keeps `http://grouplogic.com:80/content/index.cfm?ID=103`.

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't seem to remove any line: https://snipboard.io/lbHJQS.jpg

Comment: Your file changes the order of arguments. I did not address reordering. We *can*, but it adds more logic, and I didn't see any cases or reordering in the sample list (did I miss it?)

Comment: Yes but i'm counting this as other set of opts

Answer (score 0):

I see following algorithm to do this (unfortunately I don't know how to implement it):

First you sort your file, alphabetically.

Then you read your file, line by line, and if a line is a substring of the following line, it is not to be put in the resulting file.